# Signal generator: staircase on edges of square wave

Tags: redpitaya

In the signal generator, I noticed that the square wave output when set at low frequencies doesn't shoot straight up and down, but rather climbs a "staircase" instead. Is that intentional or do we try and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Square wave output response is currently optimized by a software slew rate algorithm and can be therefore reconfigured by user.